# Why I get UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when trying to open a browser using chromedriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open a chrome browser and to get google.com, using selenium chromedriver and node.js.
There is no versions mismatch between the chromedriver and the browser. However, I get the following error and the browser does not open:

(node:18512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:18512) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

This is the code that I used:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, util} = require("chromedriver");

async function openBrowser() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    await driver.get("http://google.com");
}
openBrowser();
```

Comment: `openBrowser()` does not have a `.then()` attached to it, to handle the success or failure.  that is atleast one point where that warning can come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to handle the promise of an async function is with `then` and `catch`.

For example with your function `openBrowser`:

```
openBrowser().then(driver => {
        myDriver = driver;
    }).catch(err => {
        error = { error: { message: err.message } }
    });
```